# External SDCard in Android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

How could I simulate an external SDCard in Android Emulator (/sd-ext mounted on /mnt/sdcard2 ) ? 
I'm able to define and use an internal SDCard (by emulator.exe -sdcard sdcard.img, mounted on /mnt/sdcard) but I need to simulate a device (Olivetti Olipad) that mount 2 SDs. I think there are some devices like this so could be a common problem I suppose.

Alberto

Comment: Can you please share the solution with us ? I am in same situation , I saw your comment in the post below but can you explain that a bit, or provide any reference ?

Comment: I've no reference about this but this is the model:
1) You can size your SDcard so you can size it to 1st SDCard + 2nd SDcard dimensions required.
2) make a folder in /mnt/sdcard (eg. simulated2card) and put into your 2nd SDCard content
3) after every boot your AVD (without snapshot mode) you have to soft link your content (/mnt/sdcard/simulated2card) to your needed path (in my case needed /mnt/sdcard2 ) with the command sequence:  mount -o remount,rw /; ln -s /mnt/sdcard/simulated2ndcard /mnt/sdcard2; mount -o remount,ro /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way it works on samsungs s1 is simply a folder on the internal sd card which sends you to the external sd card. so you could simulate it by creating this folder.

Comment: Yes, thank you Warpzit, I was figuring to do that. Because my app needs to use the path /mnt/sdcard2 I could do: mkdir /mnt/sdcard/simulated2ndcard; mount -o remount,rw /; ln -s /mnt/sdcard/simulated2ndcard /mnt/sdcard2; mount -o remount,ro /

Comment: On Samsung s1 it is called "external_sd". Its too bad that there isn't a way to get all external storage paths... This would make sense especially since usb devices now can be connected to our phones with android 4.0.

Comment: This way work but restarting emulator the link /mnt/sdcard2 disappears. I wonder if there is a way to make it persistent

Comment: You should change the emulator to snapshot mode. That might do the trick.